# Are seller financing monthly fees cumulative?

Tags: mortgage

**The promissory note states:
“Any payment not made by the 15 day of each month shall be subject to a 4% late payment penalty”**

I was wondering if the mortgage late fees apply to the total amount past due each month, not just the current month?
For example, if the person is 3 months past due on a $1000 monthly payment
and the late fee is 4%.   Can you calculate the late fee for the entire amount past due $3000 in the 3rd month?

Another way to express the question
(Month 1)  4% x $1000 = $40
(Month 2)  4% x $2000 = $80
(Month 3)  4% x $3000 = $120

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Read the specific contract you ste being offered. Have your lawyer read the specific contract you are being offered.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, your statement would state the amount due/past due and that's the amount subject to the late fee. Anything not paid by the due date of the previous month will carryover to the next month, and usually the late fees would be added.

So:

- Month 1 you'd have 4%*1000=$40.
- Month 2 you'd have 4%*1000 from that month + 4%*1040 from the previous month = $81.6
- Month 3 you'd have 4%*1000 from that month + 4%*2121.60 from the previous month = $124.64

and so on....

As you can see, late fees can add up very quickly.

Obviously your specific contract may be stipulating something else, so you should read the specific contract you're working on for the exact details.

Comment: Good catch, I fail to account for the compounding.

Comment: Unfortunately the promissory note only references what I have quoted above when it comes to monthly late fees.  There may be some underlying  State statue that governs what lenders are able to charge.   I'll check out NOLO before going to an attorney .    Thanks